# NodeJS JQuery file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, amazon-s3

I've been working on File Upload in NodeJS and I've been having a hard time with jQuery file upload. I get CORS error thrown at me. I followed this tutorial for File Upload on S3 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gv0PJrMDBYc&t=649s)

I'm using `s3fsImpl` `s3` `s3fs`

Here's a my route

```
router.post('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
// Check for mandatory form data to be filled
// isAuthenticated has an auth-token in the header
var auth_token = req.headers['auth-token'];
// I believe req.files.file is not getting the file itself
if (req.files.file) {
  var file_name = req.files.file;
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(file_name.path);
  if (file_name) {
    return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file_name.originalFilename, stream).then(function() {
      fs.unlink(file_name.path, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
           res.json({"status": 200, "message":"file uploaded"});
          // res.end();
        }
      });
    }); // callback ends here
  }
} else {
  res.status(400);
  res.json({
    'status': 400,
    'message': 'bad request, missing fields'
  });
  res.end();
}});
```

And here's the JQuery Ajax POST

```
$('#uploadAction').click(function() {
  uploadVal = $('#my-file').val();
  var res = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name;
  console.log(res);
  var settings = {
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "my_url",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'auth-token': 'my_auth_token'
    },
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'form-data',
    data: {'file': res},
    success: function(data) {
      $('#statusMsgs').css('background', 'green');
      $('#statusMsgs').text('File Successfully Uploaded!');
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //var obj = JSON.parse(responseText.responseText);
      $('#statusMsgs').text(textStatus);
    }
  };
  $.ajax(settings);
});
```

I've also added

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin,X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization,auth-token,Accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization,auth-token');
    next();
});
```

Here's the HTML part

```
 <input type="file" name="my_file" id="my-file" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 6px;">
<a href="#" id="uploadAction" style="background: #2D86C2;   padding: 10px;   color: #fff;   text-decoration: none;">Upload</a>
```

Comment: FYI, this works perfectly with Postman but fails when I upload a file from button click

Comment: Problem solved :) Issue was with the request payload